# Mysql UPDATE with selected data according to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I wrote a `SELECT` query to select specific values, basically it only select data that is in all 3 tables.

But when I try to update, it still updates more data (rows) than it should

Here is select

```
SELECT 
    i.id, i.group_id, i.name, u.item, u.value, u.shows, u.nr, u.type
FROM 
    items AS i
INNER JOIN 
    item_groups, item_properties2 AS u ON item_groups.id = i.group_id
WHERE 
    item_groups.idp = '1140503406'
    AND i.id = u.item
    AND u.type = 1140614900
LIMIT 
    30, 3000
```

And here is UPDATE

```
UPDATE item_properties2 AS P
INNER JOIN items ON items.id = P.item
INNER JOIN item_groups ON item_groups.idp = '1140503406'
SET P.nr = '0'
WHERE
    P.type = 1140614900`
```

It seems like it ignores my item_groups.idp = '1140503406' and instead updates everything in it, not just this value. I don't know how to make understand that it should only update data if its item_groups.idp = '1140503406' and not all item_groups.idp.

HELP

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item_groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `idp` int(11) default '0',
  `text_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `nr` int(11) default '0',
  `title` text,
  `description` text,
  `keywords` text,
  `seo_title` text,
  `seo_description` text,
  `seo_keywords` text,
  `active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `type` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `ord_alias` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `another_title` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `idp` (`idp`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;





(1339999485, 1306487541, 0, 'Scandomestic||||||||{lv}', 20, NULL, '||||||||{lv}', NULL, 'Šaldytuvai vitrinos, šaldymo vitrinos, šaldytuvas vitrina, šaldymo vitrina||||||||{lv}', 'Šaldytuvai vitrinos, šaldymo vitrinos, Šalna — šaldytuvai pramonei, šaldikliai pramonei, šaldymo skrynios, šaldytuvai vitrinos, šaldymo vitrinos, šaldymo spintos, Minsk, Polair, Snaige||||||||{lv}', 'Šaldytuvai vitrinos, šaldymo vitrinos, Šalna, šaldytuvai pramonei, šaldikliai pramonei, šaldymo skrynios, šaldytuvai vitrinos, šaldymo vitrinos, šaldymo spintos, Minsk, Polair, Snaige||||||||{lv}', 1, 0, '003_003_009_020', '||||||||{lv}'),
(1340000121, 1273586684, 0, 'Šaldymo stalai||Refrigeration tables||??????????? ???????||||{lv}Saldešanas galdi', 6, NULL, '||||||||{lv}', NULL, 'Šaldymo stalai, šaldymo stalai||||||||{lv}', 'Šaldymo stalai, Šalna — šaldytuvai pramonei, šaldikliai pramonei, šaldymo skrynios, šaldytuvai vitrinos, šaldymo vitrinos, šaldymo spintos, Electrolux, Liebherr, Whirlpool, šaldymo iranga, šaldymo kameros, šaldymo vitrinos||||||||{lv}', 'šaldymo iranga, Šaldymo skrynios, Šalna, šaldytuvai pramonei, šaldikliai pramonei, šaldymo skrynios, šaldytuvai vitrinos, šaldymo vitrinos, šaldymo spintos, Electrolux, Liebherr, Whirlpool, šaldymo iranga, šaldymo kameros, šaldymo vitrinos||||||||{lv}', 1, 2, '003_006', '||||||||{lv}'),
(1340114091, 1140503406, 0, 'Panasonic||||||||{lv}', 45, NULL, '||||||||{lv}', NULL, '||||||||{lv}', '||||||||{lv}', '||||||||{lv}', 1, 0, '002_001_045', '||||||||{lv}'),
(1340351314, 1339500892, 0, 'Mawi||Mawi||Mawi||||{lv}Mawi', 209, NULL, '||||||||{lv}', NULL, '||||||||{lv}', '||||||||{lv}', '||||||||{lv}', 1, 2, '003_004_018_209', '||||||||{lv}'),
(1340687392, 1140503406, 0, 'UPO||||||||{lv}', 47, NULL, '||||||||{lv}', NULL, 'Sharp||Sharp||Sharp||||{lv}', 'Sharp šaldytuvas-šaldiklis||Sharp fridges||Sharp||||{lv}', 'Sharp, šaldytuvas, šaldytuvai, šaldikliai, šaldiklis, šaldymo iranga, šaldymo iranga buiciai||Sharp, fridges, freezers||Sharp||||{lv}', 1, 0, '002_001_047', '||||||||{lv}');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `item_properties2`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item_properties2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `type` int(11) default NULL,
  `item` int(11) default NULL,
  `value` text,
  `shows` int(11) default NULL,
  `nr` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=78180 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `item_properties2`

```
INSERT INTO `item_properties2` (`id`, `type`, `item`, `value`, `shows`, `nr`) VALUES
(44774, 1140614843, 1146145783, '30', 0, 6),
(44775, 1140764279, 1146145783, '+1°C - +65°C', 1, 7),
(44776, 1140614891, 1146145783, 'Deže (išore ir vidus): šviesiai pilka/tamsiai pilka; dangtis: šviesiai pilka.', 1, 8),
(42360, 1140614891, 1242137094, 'Nerudijancio plieno', 1, 8),
(42361, 1140614900, 1242137094, 'Japonija', 1, 9),
(46368, 1140764407, 1209560120, 'Erdve 2l buteliui, šaldytuvas gali buti pastatomas vertikaliai, šaldymo - šildymo funkcijos.', 1, 10),
(44874, 1140614900, 1250520801, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(46380, 1146127137, 1277976190, 'Waeco CoolMatic CDF-035', 0, 0),
(46367, 1140614900, 1209560120, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(46366, 1140614891, 1209560120, 'Juoda / balta', 1, 8),
(44730, 1140614900, 1146144811, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(44728, 1140614891, 1146144811, 'Deže (išore ir vidus): šviesiai pilka, dangtis: tamsiai pilka', 1, 8),
(44727, 1140764279, 1146144811, '+1°C - +65°C', 1, 7),
(44726, 1140614843, 1146144811, '19', 0, 6),
(44725, 1140614826, 1146144811, '33', 0, 5),
(44724, 1140614802, 1146144811, '28', 0, 4),
(44723, 1157531440, 1146144811, '36 W', 0, 3),
(44721, 1140614775, 1146144811, '12/230 voltu DC/AC', 0, 1),
(44669, 1140764407, 1146140235, 'Šviesa viduje, elektroninis valdymas, patogios rankenos nešimui, erdve 2 l buteliui, išimamas metalinis krepšys', 1, 10),
(44668, 1140614900, 1146140235, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(44665, 1140764279, 1146140235, '+10 iki -18 (nustatoma elektroniniu termostatu)', 1, 7),
(44666, 1140614891, 1146140235, 'Tamsiai/šviesiai pilka', 1, 8),
(78120, 1140614792, 1352201554, '327', 1, 5),
(25927, 1140614900, 1176359569, 'USA', 0, 7),
(25926, 1141204836, 1176359569, 'yra', 0, 6),
(44664, 1140614843, 1146140235, '58', 0, 6),
(44653, 1140614900, 1146137735, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(44651, 1140614891, 1146137735, 'Tamsiai/šviesiai pilka', 1, 8),
(44648, 1140614826, 1146137735, '36', 0, 5),
(44647, 1140614802, 1146137735, '38,5', 0, 4),
(44707, 1146127137, 1207641727, 'Waeco Coolfreeze CF-110 AC', 0, 0),
(44682, 1140764407, 1207639997, 'Šviesa viduje, elektroninis valdymas, nuimamos rankenos nešimui, erdve 2 l buteliui', 1, 10),
(44680, 1140614900, 1207639997, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(44679, 1140614891, 1207639997, 'pilka', 1, 8),
(44678, 1140764279, 1207639997, '+10 iki -18', 1, 7),
(44677, 1140614843, 1207639997, '63', 0, 6),
(44676, 1140614826, 1207639997, '36', 0, 5),
(44675, 1140614802, 1207639997, '48', 0, 4),
(44674, 1157531440, 1207639997, 'Vidut. 45W', 0, 3),
(44673, 1140614792, 1207639997, '49', 0, 2),
(22032, 1140764407, 1146135011, 'Patogi rankena, mechaninis valdymas', 1, 10),
(22029, 1140614891, 1146135011, 'Tamsiai/šviesiai pilka', 1, 8),
(22031, 1140614900, 1146135011, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(22007, 1140764407, 1146133201, 'DC pajungimo laidas', 1, 10),
(22006, 1140614900, 1146133201, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(22028, 1140764279, 1146135011, '+10 iki -18 (nustatoma elektroniniu termostatu)', 1, 7),
(22027, 1140614843, 1146135011, '46.5', 0, 6),
(22026, 1140614826, 1146135011, '30', 0, 5),
(22025, 1140614802, 1146135011, '41.4', 0, 4),
(22004, 1140614891, 1146133201, 'Tamsiai/šviesiai pilka', 1, 8),
(22003, 1140764279, 1146133201, 'nuo +10 iki -18 (nustatoma elektroniniu termostatu)', 1, 7),
(22002, 1140614843, 1146133201, '56', 0, 6),
(22001, 1140614826, 1146133201, '34', 0, 5),
(22000, 1140614802, 1146133201, '47.5', 0, 4),
(21999, 1157531440, 1146133201, 'Vidut. 45W', 0, 3),
(21998, 1140614792, 1146133201, '39', 0, 2),
(46390, 1140764407, 1277976190, 'Šviesa viduje, elektroninis valdymas, patogios rankenos nešimui, erdve 2 l buteliui, išimamas metalinis krepšys', 1, 10),
(21997, 1140614775, 1146133201, '12/24 DC', 0, 1),
(46389, 1140614900, 1277976190, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(46388, 1140614891, 1277976190, 'Tamsiai/šviesiai pilka', 1, 8),
(46387, 1140764279, 1277976190, '+10 iki -18 (nustatomas elektroniniu termostatu)', 1, 7),
(42201, 1140764407, 1224489821, '', 1, 8),
(46110, 1140764407, 1140784557, '1 durys, 6 stalciai', 1, 11),
(42066, 1140614900, 1140784557, 'Baltarusija', 1, 9),
(42067, 1140614900, 1140784557, 'Baltarusija', 1, 10),
(46386, 1140614843, 1277976190, '56', 0, 6),
(46385, 1140614826, 1277976190, '34', 0, 5),
(46383, 1157531440, 1277976190, 'Vidut. 45 W', 0, 3),
(42065, 1140614891, 1140784557, 'balta', 1, 8),
(43302, 1140614900, 1140788581, 'Lietuva', 1, 9),
(43471, 1140614900, 1140790207, 'Lietuva', 1, 9),
(43470, 1140614891, 1140790207, 'balta', 1, 8),
(43469, 1140771001, 1140790207, '245', 1, 7),
(43468, 1140784675, 1140790207, '-', 1, 6),
(43467, 1140614792, 1140790207, '245', 1, 5),
(43466, 1140614843, 1140790207, '60', 0, 4),
(43465, 1140614826, 1140790207, '60', 0, 3),
(43464, 1140614802, 1140790207, '145', 0, 2),
(43463, 1140770892, 1140790207, '0.73', 0, 1),
(43462, 1140614720, 1140790207, 'A', 0, 0),
(53894, 1140771001, 1304447043, '-', 1, 7),
(43448, 1140614900, 1140789961, 'Lietuva', 1, 9),
(43447, 1140614891, 1140789961, 'Balta', 1, 8),
(43446, 1140771001, 1140789961, '100', 1, 7),
(43445, 1140784675, 1140789961, '-', 1, 6),
(43444, 1140614792, 1140789961, '100', 1, 5),
(43443, 1140614843, 1140789961, '60', 0, 4),
(43442, 1140614826, 1140789961, '56', 0, 3),
(43441, 1140614802, 1140789961, '85', 0, 2),
(43460, 1140614900, 1140786679, 'Lietuva', 1, 9),
(43459, 1140614891, 1140786679, 'balta', 1, 8),
(43458, 1140771001, 1140786679, '245', 1, 7),
(43457, 1140784675, 1140786679, '-', 1, 6),
(43456, 1140614792, 1140786679, '245', 1, 5),
(43455, 1140614843, 1140786679, '60', 0, 4),
(43454, 1140614826, 1140786679, '60', 0, 3),
(43453, 1140614802, 1140786679, '145', 0, 2),
(43452, 1140770892, 1140786679, '0.73', 0, 1),
(43451, 1140614720, 1140786679, 'A', 0, 0),
(23707, 1140614900, 1140786959, 'Italija ', 1, 10),
(23706, 1140614891, 1140786959, 'balta ', 1, 9),
(23705, 1140771001, 1140786959, '140 ', 1, 8),
(23704, 1140784675, 1140786959, '-', 1, 7),
(23703, 1140614792, 1140786959, '140 ', 1, 6),
(23702, 1140614843, 1140786959, '60 ', 0, 5),
(23701, 1140614826, 1140786959, '60 ', 0, 4),
(23700, 1140614802, 1140786959, '105 ', 0, 3),
(23699, 1140770892, 1140786959, '0.84 ', 0, 2),
(23698, 1140614720, 1140786959, 'B ', 0, 1),
(23696, 1140614909, 1140787174, 'Rusija ', 1, 11),
(23695, 1140614900, 1140787174, 'Italija ', 1, 10),
(23694, 1140614891, 1140787174, 'balta ', 1, 9),
(23693, 1140771001, 1140787174, '275 ', 1, 8),
(23692, 1140784675, 1140787174, '-', 1, 7),
(23691, 1140614792, 1140787174, '275 ', 1, 6),
(23690, 1140614843, 1140787174, '60 ', 0, 5),
(23689, 1140614826, 1140787174, '60 ', 0, 4),
(23688, 1140614802, 1140787174, '167 ', 0, 3),
(23687, 1140770892, 1140787174, '1.1 ', 0, 2),
(23686, 1140614720, 1140787174, 'B ', 0, 1),
(23717, 1140614891, 1140787419, 'balta ', 1, 9),
(23716, 1140771001, 1140787419, '275 ', 1, 8),
(23715, 1140784675, 1140787419, '-', 1, 7),
(23714, 1140614792, 1140787419, '275 ', 1, 6),
(23713, 1140614843, 1140787419, '60 ', 0, 5),
(23712, 1140614826, 1140787419, '60 ', 0, 4),
(23711, 1140614802, 1140787419, '167 ', 0, 3),
(23710, 1140770892, 1140787419, '1.1 ', 0, 2),
(23709, 1140614720, 1140787419, 'B ', 0, 1),
(43785, 1140764407, 1159857676, 'Plasmacluster technologija, greito šaldymo funkcija.', 1, 10),
(43783, 1140614900, 1159857676, 'Japonija', 1, 9),
(43782, 1140614891, 1159857676, 'Sidabro', 1, 8),
(43781, 1140771001, 1159857676, '215', 1, 7),
(43780, 1140784675, 1159857676, '358', 1, 6),
(41632, 1140614900, 1140787900, 'Kinija', 1, 8),
(41631, 1140614891, 1140787900, 'balta||white', 1, 7),
(41630, 1140771001, 1140787900, '-', 1, 6),
(41629, 1140784675, 1140787900, '-', 1, 5),
(41628, 1140614792, 1140787900, '45', 1, 4),
(41627, 1140614826, 1140787900, '44', 0, 3),
(41626, 1140614802, 1140787900, '82', 0, 2),
(41625, 1140770892, 1140787900, '0.8', 0, 1),
(41624, 1140614720, 1140787900, 'A', 0, 0),
(42079, 1140764407, 1140788111, '1 durys, tik šaldytuvas be šaldiklio.', 1, 10),
(42077, 1140614900, 1140788111, 'Baltarusija', 1, 9),
(42076, 1140614891, 1140788111, 'Balta', 1, 8),
(42075, 1140771001, 1140788111, '-', 1, 7),
(42074, 1140784675, 1140788111, '285', 1, 6),
(42073, 1140614792, 1140788111, '285', 1, 5),
(42072, 1140614843, 1140788111, '60', 0, 4),
(42071, 1140614826, 1140788111, '60', 0, 3),
(42070, 1140614802, 1140788111, '150', 0, 2),
(42759, 1140614900, 1140788367, 'Lietuva', 1, 9),
(42758, 1140614891, 1140788367, 'balta', 1, 8),
(42757, 1140771001, 1140788367, '-', 1, 7),
(42756, 1140784675, 1140788367, '127', 1, 6),
(42755, 1140614792, 1140788367, '127', 1, 5),
(42754, 1140614843, 1140788367, '60', 0, 4),
(42753, 1140614826, 1140788367, '56', 0, 3),
(43293, 1140614720, 1140788581, 'A', 0, 0),
(43294, 1140770892, 1140788581, '0.46', 0, 1),
(43301, 1140614891, 1140788581, 'balta', 1, 8),
(43300, 1140771001, 1140788581, '-', 1, 7),
(43299, 1140784675, 1140788581, '275', 1, 6),
(42191, 1140614900, 1140788826, 'Baltarusija', 1, 9),
(42190, 1140614891, 1140788826, 'balta', 1, 8),
(42189, 1140771001, 1140788826, '115', 1, 7),
(42188, 1140784675, 1140788826, '220', 1, 6),
(42187, 1140614792, 1140788826, '335', 1, 5),
(42186, 1140614843, 1140788826, '60', 0, 4),
(42185, 1140614826, 1140788826, '60', 0, 3),
(42184, 1140614802, 1140788826, '176', 0, 2),
(42179, 1140614900, 1140789085, 'Baltarusija', 1, 9),
(42178, 1140614891, 1140789085, 'balta', 1, 8),
(42177, 1140771001, 1140789085, '80', 1, 7),
(42176, 1140784675, 1140789085, '268', 1, 6),
(42175, 1140614792, 1140789085, '348', 1, 5),
(42174, 1140614843, 1140789085, '60', 0, 4),
(43522, 1140614891, 1140789239, 'balta ', 1, 9),
(43521, 1140771001, 1140789239, '- ', 1, 8),
(43520, 1140784675, 1140789239, '245 ', 1, 7),
(43519, 1140614792, 1140789239, '245 ', 1, 6),
(43518, 1140614843, 1140789239, '60 ', 0, 5),
(43517, 1140614826, 1140789239, '60 ', 0, 4),
(43516, 1140614802, 1140789239, '131 ', 0, 3),
(43515, 1140770892, 1140789239, '1,2 ', 0, 2),
(43514, 1140614720, 1140789239, 'B ', 0, 1),
(46661, 1140614826, 1283262225, '', 1, 1),
(41743, 1140784675, 1224573246, '106', 1, 6),
(43500, 1140614900, 1228469272, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(28009, 1140614900, 1140790832, 'Italija ', 1, 10),
(28008, 1140614891, 1140790832, 'balta ', 1, 9),
(28007, 1140771001, 1140790832, '40 ', 1, 8),
(28006, 1140784675, 1140790832, '178 ', 1, 7),
(28005, 1140614792, 1140790832, '218 ', 1, 6),
(28004, 1140614843, 1140790832, '57 ', 0, 5),
(28003, 1140614826, 1140790832, '50 ', 0, 4),
(28002, 1140614802, 1140790832, '154 ', 0, 3),
(28001, 1140770892, 1140790832, '0.75 ', 0, 2),
(28000, 1140614720, 1140790832, 'A ', 0, 1),
(40313, 0, 1141202290, '', 0, 6),
(41145, 1140614900, 1221565412, 'Vokietija', 1, 9),
(41280, 1140614900, 1222331102, 'Italija', 1, 9),
(41124, 1140614900, 1140791004, 'Italija', 1, 9),
(41123, 1140614891, 1140791004, 'gelsva', 1, 8),
(41122, 1140771001, 1140791004, '83', 1, 7),
(41121, 1140784675, 1140791004, '218', 1, 6),
(41120, 1140614792, 1140791004, '301', 1, 5),
(41119, 1140614843, 1140791004, '65', 0, 4),
(41118, 1140614826, 1140791004, '60', 0, 3),
(41117, 1140614802, 1140791004, '188', 0, 2),
(28047, 1140614909, 1140791385, 'Italija ', 1, 11),
(28046, 1140614900, 1140791385, 'Italija ', 1, 10),
(28045, 1140614891, 1140791385, 'balta ', 1, 9),
(28044, 1140771001, 1140791385, '35 ', 1, 8),
(28043, 1140784675, 1140791385, '179 ', 1, 7),
(28042, 1140614792, 1140791385, '214 ', 1, 6),
(28041, 1140614843, 1140791385, '58 ', 0, 5),
(28040, 1140614826, 1140791385, '50 ', 0, 4),
(28039, 1140614802, 1140791385, '141 ', 0, 3),
(28038, 1140770892, 1140791385, '0.75 ', 0, 2),
(28037, 1140614720, 1140791385, 'A ', 0, 1),
(28036, 1140764407, 1140791820, '\\"automatinis šaldytuvo atitirpinimas, kamera viršuje\\"', 1, 12),
(28035, 1140614909, 1140791820, 'Italija ', 1, 11),
(28034, 1140614900, 1140791820, 'Italija ', 1, 10),
(28033, 1140614891, 1140791820, 'inox ', 1, 9),
(28032, 1140771001, 1140791820, '49 ', 1, 8),
(28031, 1140784675, 1140791820, '194 ', 1, 7),
(28030, 1140614792, 1140791820, '243 ', 1, 6),
(28029, 1140614843, 1140791820, '58 ', 0, 5),
(28028, 1140614826, 1140791820, '55 ', 0, 4),
(28027, 1140614802, 1140791820, '141 ', 0, 3),
(28026, 1140770892, 1140791820, '1.1 ', 0, 2),
(28025, 1140614720, 1140791820, 'B ', 0, 1),
(28059, 1140614909, 1140791988, 'Italija ', 1, 11),
(28058, 1140614900, 1140791988, 'Italija ', 1, 10),
(28057, 1140614891, 1140791988, 'inox ', 1, 9),
(28056, 1140771001, 1140791988, '55 ', 1, 8),
(28055, 1140784675, 1140791988, '216 ', 1, 7),
(28054, 1140614792, 1140791988, '271 ', 1, 6),
(28053, 1140614843, 1140791988, '58 ', 0, 5),
(28052, 1140614826, 1140791988, '54 ', 0, 4),
(28051, 1140614802, 1140791988, '154 ', 0, 3),
(28050, 1140770892, 1140791988, '0.8 ', 0, 2),
(35415, 1140764407, 1140792326, 'automatinis šaldytuvo atitirpinimas, šaldiklis - \\"no frost\\"', 1, 12),
(35414, 1140614909, 1140792326, 'Turkija ', 1, 11),
(35413, 1140614900, 1140792326, 'Turkija ', 1, 10),
(35412, 1140614891, 1140792326, 'balta ', 1, 9),
(35411, 1140771001, 1140792326, '96 ', 1, 8),
(35410, 1140784675, 1140792326, '162 ', 1, 7),
(35409, 1140614792, 1140792326, '258 ', 1, 6),
(23595, 0, 1140792462, '', 0, 14);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item_property_groups2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` text,
  `unit` text,
  `nr` tinyint(4) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `item_property_groups2`

```
INSERT INTO `item_property_groups2` (`id`, `name`, `unit`, `nr`) VALUES
(1140614720, 'Energijos klasė||Energy Class||Класс электронергии||Energijos klasė||{lv}Enerģijas klase', '||||||||{lv}', 9),
(1140614775, 'El. įtampa||Voltage||Эл. напряжение||El. įtampa||{lv}Elektriskais spriegums', '||||||||{lv}', 11),
(1140614792, 'Bendras tūris, L||Total capacity, L||Общий объем, Л||Bendras tūris||{lv}Kopējais apjoms (litri)', 'litrai||litrai||litrai||litrai||{lv}litri', 4),
(1140614802, 'Aukštis (cm.)||Height||Высота (см)||Aukštis||{lv}Augstums (cm)', 'cm||cm||cm||cm||{lv}cm', 1),
(1140614826, 'Plotis (cm.)||Width (cm.)||Ширина  (см.)||Plotis||{lv}Platums (cm)', 'cm||cm||cm||cm||{lv}cm', 37),
(1140614843, 'Gylis (cm)||Depth (cm)||Глубина (см)||Gylis||{lv}Dziļums (cm)', 'cm||cm||cm||cm||{lv}cm', 16),
(1140614891, 'Spalva||Color||Цвет||Farbe||{lv}Krāsa', '||||||||{lv}', 38),
(1140614900, 'Gamintojas||Producer||Производитель||Gamintojas||{lv}Ražotājs', '||||||||{lv}', 24);
```

Comment: How is the `item_groups` table related to the `items` and `item_properties2` tables? You should specify a `JOIN` condition based on a column id like what you did `ON items.id = p.item` something like `item_groups.idp = items.someid` instead of `item_groups.idp = '1140503406'`

Comment: Seems like you're confusing the ON clause with the WHERE clause

Comment: item_groups is related to items. item_groups 'id' is 'group_id' in items. Its not really related to item_properties2. That the problem atleast i think. So i need to update with item table help.

Comment: Basically if i still didnt wrote clear enough. I need to update item_properties2.nr to 0 .  And it should only select those data that is : item_properties2.type = 1140614900` and item_groups.idp = 1140503406 . Yet item_groups isnt directly connected to item_properties2 as far as i understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the predicate `items_groups.idp = '1140503406'` to the `WHERE` clause, with a `JOIN` condition `item_groups.idp = items.group_id` instead of it, like so:

```
UPDATE item_properties2 AS P
INNER JOIN items ON items.id = P.item
INNER JOIN item_groups ON item_groups.idp = items.group_id 
SET P.nr = '0'
WHERE P.type = 1140614900
  AND items_groups.idp = '1140503406';
```

Comment: didnt work i get zero rows affected, something still missing...if only i wasnt so clueless

Comment: @hihi - Can you please post some sample data. This should work properly. Test it with a normal select instead of an `UPDATE`.

Comment: i seem to to have enough space to post create table and data in same comment

Comment: @hihi - You have the whatever space you want in your question. Update it with some sample data of your tables. Thanks

Comment: I seem to have made mistake item_groups.id = items.group_id. and i need those in  item_groups.idp = '1140503406'.

Comment: I posted some sample data, dont know how to put it in spoiler

Comment: UPDATE item_properties2 AS P
INNER JOIN items ON items.id = P.item
INNER JOIN item_groups ON item_groups.id = items.group_id 
SET P.nr = '0'
WHERE P.type = 1140614900
  AND item_groups.idp = '1140503406' this somehow worker correctly, even though before it didnt work... dont know why, maybe bugs...